# Google Spreadsheet: How can I leave the Script Editor open in another tab after refreshing a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps-script-editor

Whenever I refresh a spreadsheet (after having changed some of its Apps Scripts code) with  `CMD` - `R`, Safari closes the script editor tab automatically.

How can I avoid that this tab is being closed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make an edit in the script, but don't save. Refresh the spreadsheet. The tab with the script will ask you if you want to close the tab, so say no. It won't close on you anymore after that.

Also, you can use Tools > Script Manager from the spreadsheet to run functions, or even run them directly from the script editor if you don't want to refresh.